# Update the positions' property of Polyline in dash-leaflet through a callback

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash, dash-leaflet

How is it possible to update the positions property of Polyline through a callback? I tried `value` and `data` in the callback's `Output` property, but it seems it did not work.

```py
import dash_leaflet as dl
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Output, Input, State, callback

app = Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Button(id="btn_run"),
    dl.Map(dl.TileLayer(),
           dl.Polyline(positions=[], id='position-data'),
           center=[56, 10], zoom=6, style={'height': '50vh'}))


@app.callback(Output('position-data', 'value'),
              Input("btn_run", "n_clicks"),
              prevent_initial_call=True)
def on_click(n_clicks):
    positions = [[49.799558, 6.712016], [50.58268, 5.549233]]
    return positions


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all there are some errors in your code:

- The `Map` object needs a list of elements (the `children` parameter), so you need to write the parameters like this: `Map([dl.TileLayer(...), dl.Polyline(...)])`. Also, each object has (often) some properties. In this case you have: `center`, `zoom`, `style`. These properties must be written outside the `children` parameter because they are property of the web object. So the result is:

```py
dl.Map([dl.TileLayer(),
       dl.Polyline(positions=[], id='position-data')],
       center=[56, 10], zoom=6, style={'height': '50vh'})
```

- The same reasoning applies to the `Div` object:

```py
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button(id="btn_run"),
    dl.Map([dl.TileLayer(),
           dl.Polyline(positions=[], id='position-data')],
           center=[56, 10], zoom=6, style={'height': '50vh'})
])
```

Now, if you want to change the `positions` property, why didn't you use it directly? So, in the `Output` callback write `positions` and the result is the following:

```py
@app.callback(Output('position-data', 'positions'),
              Input("btn_run", "n_clicks"),
              prevent_initial_call=True)
def on_click(n_clicks):
    positions = [[49.799558, 6.712016], [50.58268, 5.549233]]
    return positions
```

[image]